# Issue with constructor signatures implementing Vector class in Java

Tags: java, game-engine, vector-graphics

I am building a basic physics engine in Java just to get the hang of the language, and I've run into a problem that I think I know how to solve, but not in any elegant way.

I would like for there to be two possible constructors for my PVector class, one that accepts an x and a y coordinate and one that accepts an angle and a radius.

For example, we would have `public PVector(double x, double y)` as the signature for the first and `public PVector(double arg, double rad)` as the second. However, as you all know, you cannot have two methods with the same signature in a class because there's no way for Java to know which method to call.

I could fuse the two constructors and take a third argument like a boolean (isPolar) or use flags, but both of those methods seem clunky. I would just like to know what is the most idiomatic, sensible way to do something like this in Java. Any and all advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a factory or static [factory methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use static factories instead.

Make your constructor private, and make public static methods with appropriate names:

```
public static PVector makeFromXAndY(double x, double y) {
    return new PVector(...);
}

public static PVector makeFromArgAndRadius(double arg, double radius) {
    return new PVector(...);
}

private PVector(double x, double y) {
    ....
}
```

The book Effective Java by Joshua Bloch is very good on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static method that constructs a vector, similarly to a factory, calling a private constructor:

```
public static PVector fromAngle(double r, double theta){
    return new PVector(/*trig here*/);
}
```

You'd call it as `PVector v = PVector.fromAngle(3, Math.PI)`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a public constructor, use static factory methods `ofCartesian` and `ofPolar` that call a private constructor but make it clear what the meaning of the parameters is.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question,You may required some required fields and some optional fields. You can use **Builder pattern** to create instance .

> [Builder Pattern link](https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/)

2. Even if one create static methods ,you need one all parameter constructor and pass parameter accordingly by putting some logic in static methods.